# Need help with a perl program

Tags: arrays, perl, loops, hash, shift

Ok, so I am trying take a hash and if any string in an array contains the key(not value actual key name) in the hash discard it. Else print out the string. This issue is with a portion of the findHidden sub routine. I have tried a lot of different things, I will comment below where I have issues. I'm sure someone has an answer, always get one on stack overflow :)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Configure
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
#
sub findHidden;
sub GetInfo; 
sub defineHash;
##############

$passwd = '/etc/passwd';
%info = ();

sub GetInfo {
        die "Cannot open: $passwd"
        unless (open(PW,$passwd));
        while(<PW>) {
                chomp;
                my ($uname,$junk1,$junk2,$junk3,$domain,$home) = split(':', $_);
                next unless ($home =~ /vs/);
                %info = (
                        domain  => $domain,
                        home    => "$home/",
                        tmp     => "$home/tmp",
                        htdocs  => "$home/www/htdocs",
                        cgibin  => "$home/www/cgi\-bin",
                );
                print "\n" . $info{domain} . "\n";
                print "+"x40,"\n\n";
                findHidden($info{tmp});
        }
}
sub findHidden {
        defineHash;
        print "Searching " . $_[0] . "\n";
        print "-"x30,"\n\n";
        @hidden = `find $_[0] -iname ".*"`;
        for(@hidden) {
                foreach $key (keys % hExcludes) {
                        if ($_ =~ /$key/){    #
                                last;         # This portion is 
                        }else{                # Only an issue when using more
                                print "$_";   # than 2 keys in my hash.
                                last;
                        }
                }
        }
}
sub defineHash {
        %hExcludes = ();
        %hExcludes = map { $_, 1 } (
                'spamd','.nfs'     # If I add another key here, it breaks.
        );

        %knownExploits = 
                ( );
        print Dumper \%hExcludes;
}
GetInfo;
```

This Works, and prints out something like this:

**/somedir/tmp/.testthis**
**/somedir/tmp/.sdkfbsdif**
**/somedir/tmp/.asdasdasd**

I understand why It is not working, because it is looping through the keys where some are false and some are positive, I just cannot think of how to make it do what I want, please assume I might want to you 10 keys. I know there are ways to do it without using hash key values for my excludes but it is what I want to accomplish.

I have also tried shift @hidden as below to no avail.

```
                foreach $key (keys % hExcludes) {
                        if ($_ =~ /$key/){    #
                                last;         #
                                shift @hidden;# This portion is 
                        }else{                # Only an issue when using more
                                print "$_";   # than 2 keys in my hash.
                                last;
                        }
```

Also, keep in mind that things only stop working when I add the third...or more keys.

```
        %hExcludes = map { $_, 1 } (
                'spamd','.nfs','key3'     # If I add another key here, it breaks
        );
```

Comment: You just need to say what you mean with "it breaks"? One hint: you are substtuting variables whose values contain metacharacters in regexes, i.e. ".nfs". You may want to write /\Q$key\E/ to provide for quotation.

Comment: -1 The code you posted cannot possibly "work", as it does not even compile. You should be sure to post the exact same code as what you have run!

Answer (score 3):

What you need is this:

```
    @hidden = `find $_[0] -iname ".*"`;
    for(@hidden) {
        undef $isExcluded;
        foreach $key (keys % hExcludes) {
            if ($_ =~ /$key/){
                $isExcluded=1;
                last;
            }
        }
        if( ! $isExcluded ) {
            print "$_";
        }
    }
```

Whatever happened in your scan through the keys of hExcludes, the code encountered a `last` on the first key and did not process any more. You need to set a flag and continue iterating until either there are no more keys to set, or a match is found. Then you can print out the values that were not matched.

Comment: Question, do you think this method is faster than not using hash keys to match?

Comment: Actually you aren't really using hash keys, as the only use you put the hash to is to create an array of unique regular expressions to test again. By using a hash you got unique tests for free, but had to spend time creating an array from the hash before you could use it.

If the required test has been to match explicit file names, that is the test was `$_==$key` then it could have been written faster as `exists $hExcludes{$_}` and the inner loop avoided.

Comment: makes sense, only thing is I need a if contains not an explicit match.